# how to add sign in page on my facebook page?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an app.
I have my own facebook and twitter pages.
In app when user click on facebook button he should navigate to my facebook page.
once he navigate to my page at top of page login option should come or if he is already login his profile pic shold come?
How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried integration code to facebook page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Link Generator, Link generator will generate the Link of page which you want to open when user click on button. Here is the site which will help you to create Link of page for FaceBook:

http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/

You can also visit http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/ and can post your question there, you might get more help.